# ¿Como guardar un script de python desde la terminal de Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, interfaz-gráfica, terminal

Ya ejecuté un programa en la terminal de Ubuntu usando Python, pero mi duda es como guardarlo ahi directamente sin tener que usar un editor de codigo. ¿Hay algun comando?

Comment: ¿Creo que sé a lo que te refieres, pero podrías dar un ejemplo de qué es lo que estás haciendo para que te podamos ayudar con más precisión?

Answer (score 2):

Si te refieres a la sesión interactiva de Python, puedes usar readline. Basta con importarlo y en el momento que quieras guardar, escribir el comando.

```
import readline
readline.write_history_file('nombre_o_ruta_del_archivo.py')
```

También puede ser extensión .txt si no lo quieres guardar en ese momento como un script.

Comment: Te sugiero que esperes a qué aclare a qué se refiere, para que las posibles respuestas sean más enfocadas. De todas maneras, no conocía `readline.write_history_file`. Buena respuesta para una pregunta ambigua.

Comment: @Cuauhtli si tienes razón, de igual manera si hace la aclaración actualizo la respuesta para que sea acorde con ello, de todos modos que bueno que la respuesta fue útil.